# Test that a request was sent in a Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I have a controller that posts an HTTP request on a certain action, how do I test/assert that the request is actually being sent?

Comment: What have you tried? Testing controllers/requests is not new, and that's lots of examples/help/tools out there.

Comment: I have other tests to assert a response but couldn't find one to assert that a request was sent

Answer (score 0):

I would just test the response or the higher level action (like what does this thing do?).  But if you want to test the interactions (maybe routes check etc?) then mock it up.  Below are some ideas.

```
# test where the request goes
request = ActionController::TestRequest.new
request.query_parameters[:foo] = "bar"
request.path = "/"
ActionController::Routing::Routes.recognize(request)
assert_equal({"controller"=>"your_controller","action"=>"index"}, request.path_parameters)
# other tests here if you want
```

Rspec type test:

```
# test that the controller will receive it
controller = YourController.new
controller.should respond_to(:create)
```